# Открыть порт на Debian 9

Tags: linux

Подскажите пожалуйста - как открыть порт в debian 9, например, 25-й. А то столько всяких пособий, которые просто противоречат друг другу и ничего четкого и вразумительного нет.

перенесено из «ответа»:

Значит, описываю ситуацию подробнее. Есть сервер на Debian 9, на нем нужно организовать виртуал хосты\поддомены, которые будут привязаны каждый к своему IP, с которых будет идти рассылки. Делал через Postfix instances, прописывая через main.cf и master.cf. В итоге - на главном хосте все работает, а два виртуала не работают - для них закрыт порт 25 и остальные. Прописывал в iptables все что можно - полный ноль. Если пишу в главном main.cf, принудительно: smtp_bind_address = Х.Х.Х.Х smtp_helo_name = mail1.new.com myhostname = mail1.new.com То только тогда для него как-то открывается порт и идет рассылка. Но вместе они не работают, только по отдельности. Сами виртуал хосты через браузер не открываются, ERR Connection Timed Out, главные сайт сам открывается.

---

Все ip добавлены в систему и в ней видны

Вообщем, ситуация решилась, нужно было потасовать настройки в main.cf.

Comment: Все порты и так открыты по умолчанию, ничего делать не нужно

Comment: `smtp_bind_address = Х.Х.Х.Х` — чтобы программа (любая) могла слушать соединения на каком-либо ip-адресе, этот ip-адрес как минимум должен быть известен вашей операционной системе. посмотреть, какие адреса ей известны: `$ ip a`.

Comment: [Я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: написал даже [вопросо-ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1259314/178576) для проверки доступности связки ip:port.

Answer (score 2):

Если есть `ufw` то просто `# ufw allow 25` ну еще можно дописать протокол `25/tcp` или `udp` Если нет ufw то должен быть `IPTABLES` будет он не ладен)

```
iptables -I INPUT --dport 25 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: ответ — тоже классика. именно про подобные ответы автор вопроса и написал: «А то столько всяких пособий, которые просто противоречат друг другу и ничего четкого и вразумительного нет». // не стоило писать ответ на невразумительно заданный вопрос: просто рискуете добавить во вселенную ещё одну столь же невразумительную инструкцию.

Comment: почему я вам комментарий написал: потому что ваш ответ скорее всего никак не поможет спрашивающему: ведь он, с вероятностью примерно 80% пытается подключиться со своего компьютера к какому-нибудь smtp серверу, указывая порт 25, исходящий трафик на который со 100%-ной вероятностью заблокирован провайдером.

Comment: @aleksandr давайте немного разберем) Что 'ufw' что 'iptables' порты командой откроют. Если автору это не помогло, то нужно смотреть глубже. А так, на секундочку, порты я открыл. И да, как коментарий выше, я скажу что порты по дэфолту открыты!

Comment: давайте не будем ничего разбирать, а остановимся на том, что автор вопроса даже не уточнил, о входящих или исходящих соединениях идёт речь, а потому ваш ответ отвечает на всё что угодно кроме исходного вопроса (который, повторюсь, абсолютно неясен).