# netcat: проверка доступности связки ip:port

Tags: linux, netcat

моему серверу выделено несколько ip-адресов. они добавлены к внешнему интерфейсу (в примере фигурируют интерфейс `eth0` и адреса `192.168.2.120` и `192.168.2.188`, которые, конечно, не относятся к публичным, но это же только пример):

```
$ ip a l dev eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:fd:45:fd:10:4c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.120/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.188/24 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

как мне с помощью программы `nc` (`netcat`) проверить одновременную доступность какого-нибудь порта на каждом из адресов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- указать прослушиваемый адрес можно с помощью опции `-s адрес`.
- указать прослушиваемый порт можно с помощью опции `-p порт`

для примера возьмём порт 1024 (порты с меньшими номерами требуют повышенных привилегий — надо будет запускать программу `nc` от имени пользователя `root`).

запустите на сервере для каждой пары `ip:port` такую примерно команду:

```
$ while :; do echo "ip: 192.168.2.188 port:1024" | nc -q 1 -l -s 192.168.2.188 -p 1024 >/dev/null 2>&1 || break; done &
```

понятно, что в команде `echo` и в параметрах `nc` должны фигурировать одни и те же ip-адреса и порты, чтобы ответы можно было отличить.

а теперь из внешнего (для сервера) мира с помощью той же программы `nc` проверьте, что получаете ответ от сервера:

```
$ nc 192.168.2.188 1024
ip: 192.168.2.188 port:1024
```

и так для каждой пары `ip:port`. если получаете что-нибудь вроде:

```
(UNKNOWN) [192.168.2.188] 1024 (?) : Connection refused
```

то значит доступа (по крайней мере от вашего локального компьютера до сервера) к данному ip-адресу и на указанном порту — нет.

---

проверять можно и с помощью http-клиента («браузера»). для этого надо добавить немного http-информации в команду `echo`, приведя её примерно к такому виду:

```
echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\nip: 192.168.2.188 port:1024"
```

тогда по ссылке `http://192.168.2.188:1024` должно отобразиться то же самое сообщение от запущенной на сервере программы `nc`.

но это подойдёт не для всех портов — например, открывать соединение на 25-м порту протестированные мной http-клиенты *firefox* и *chromium* отказались наотрез.

---

убить запущенные не сервере процессы `nc` можно с помощью команды:

```
$ kill номер.процесса
```

увидеть номера процессов, содержащих в имени `nc` (и переданные процессам параметры), можно так:

```
$ pgrep -a nc
```